# SharePoint 2013 Usage report does NOT bulk data to the excel report

Tags: 2013, web-analytics, site-usage

**Q:I wonder if there is any boundary that is making my Usage report failing or if I missed any step in the configuration ???.**
[image]
I run the report on a Sharepoint web app "Mysite".

After follow the troubleshooting described here.
http://blog.fpweb.net/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2013-web-analytics/#.V3UA97h96Uk

I did not find any error or failure, furthermore the sql query returns 9 millions rows, database size is 27 Gb, i see data in the view [dbo].[RequestUsage], but still not able to see a single figure in the Excel report usage.

Timer jobs does not fail and ULS seems ok:

Starting usage log files (1) import: D:\SharePoint\Usage\MicroblogUsageTelemetry.
Deleting usage log file 'D:\SharePoint\Usage\RequestUsage\xxxx-20160624-2236-20160624-22450.usage' after data import.
Deleting usage log file 'D:\SharePoint\Usage\MicroblogUsageTelemetry\xxxxx-20160624-2220-20160624-22450.usage' after data import.
Deleting usage log file 'D:\SharePoint\Usage\SqlIoData\xxxxx-20160624-2243-20160624-22440.usage' after data import.
Starting usage log files (11) import: D:\SharePoint\Usage\RequestUsage.